# Java Project: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: unit-testing, spring, junit

I have a Java Project in which I am writing a simple JUNIT test case.  I have copied the applicatinoContext.xml file into the root java source directory.  I've tried it with some of the recommended settings I have read of here on StackOverflow but still get the same error.  Is this error happening due to my project being a java project and NOT a web project, or does that even matter?  I'm not sure where im going wrong.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"C:/projs/sortation/src/main/java/applicationContext.xml"})
// Also tried these settings but they also didnt work,
//@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
//@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
public class TestSS {

    @Autowired
    private EmsDao dao;

    @Test
    public void getSites() {

        List<String> batchid = dao.getList();

        for (String s : batchid) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the error say specifically it can't find the file (`FileNotFoundException`)? Could you paste the stack trace?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like you are using maven (`src/main/java)`. In this case put the `applicationContext.xml` file in the `src/main/resources` directory. It will be copied in the classpath directory and you should be able to access it with

```
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
```

From the [Spring-Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html): A plain path, for example "context.xml", will be treated as a classpath resource **from the same package in which the test class is defined**. A path starting with a slash is treated as a **fully qualified classpath location**, for example "/org/example/config.xml".

So it's important that you add the slash when referencing the file in the root directory of the classpath.

If you work with the absolute file path you have to use 'file:C:...' (if I understand the documentation correctly).

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions worked.  I moved the applicationContext.xml to the resources directory and added the slash to the context configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Funny that Spring MVC runs just fine with it in the WEB-INF/ folder, but Junit is left scratching it's head.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I was using the following plugin for tests:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <useFile>true</useFile>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The test were running fine in the IDE (eclipse sts), but failed when using command **mvn test**.

After a lot of trial and error, I figured the solution was to remove parallel testing, the following two lines from the plugin configuration above:

```
    <parallel>methods</parallel>
    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
```

Hope that this helps someone out!

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue because `during bootstrapping my spring project` 
using the class that implements `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and inside `onApplicationEvent` function **it throws an exception**

> so make sure that your application bootstrap points do not throw any exception

in my case, I was using [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) for testing so to debug the test process use this command

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue, and that is when a Bean (@Bean) was not instantiated properly as it was not given the correct parameters in my test class.

Comment: Sometime the names are differents, for example:

In configuration ---->
Bean
fun createPromotionService() = CreatePromotionService()
In test. ------>   MockBean
  private lateinit var createPromotion