# How to fix "Failed to load ApplicationContext" error with junit testing in Spring framework?

Tags: java, json, spring, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to create a junit test for the first time, when i run the test i get the follow error:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:314)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:312)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:396)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I've already tried multiple adding muultiple dependecies but none of them are solving my error. My code:

```
package api.javajuke.tests;

import api.javajuke.res.PlaylistController;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static 
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static 
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PlaylistControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private PlaylistController playlistController;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(playlistController).build();
}

@Test
public void testPlaylistController() throws Exception {

mockMvc.perform(get("/playlist/1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("Playlist 1")));
}
}
```

I'm trying to check if my json response contains a element named "name" and matches the name "Playlist 1". See below for my json response with api call /playlist/1:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Playlist 1",
"tracks": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "path": "example/path/1",
        "title": null,
        "artist": null,
        "duration": 0,
        "album": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "path": "example/path/2",
        "title": null,
        "artist": null,
        "duration": 0,
        "album": null
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance, hope anyone can help me and solve the error!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058294/java-project-failed-to-load-applicationcontext

Comment: You are using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` but don't have an `@ContextConfiugration` apparently your test doesn't need one so remove the `@RunWith`.